# Checkbox Check/Uncheck in User Controls

Tags: vb.net

Here is how it will present information when form loads, what I want to do is when I press the button (without select any checkbox) to show me error there isn't selected any rows.
And if I click on the first checkbox and click the button to show me message (Okay you selected ID=% row)
so in my User Control I put Tag = Number from database for each control created

[image: Picture1]

In button "Done" I add this (in Form)

```
Private Sub btnTaskDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTaskDone.Click
    If FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.OfType(Of UserTasks)().Any(Function(cb) cb.CheckBox1.Checked = False) Then
        'At least one CheckBox in myGroupBox is checked.
        MsgBox("Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Yeyy!")
    Else
        MsgBox("No Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
    End If
End Sub
```

and here is my call from DB to fill the user control:

```
Private Sub GenerateTasksUser()
    FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetTasksUser()
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim listItems As UserTasks() = New UserTasks(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
            For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New UserTasks()
                    listItems(i) = listItem
                    listItems(i).Width = FlowLayoutPanel3.Width - 24
                    listItems(i).TaskTitle = row("taskstitle").ToString()
                    listItems(i).TaskSubject = row("tasksubject").ToString()
                    listItems(i).TaskFrom = row("taskfromname").ToString()
                    listItems(i).Tag = row("ID").ToString()
                    listItems(i).CheckBoxText = row("taskstatus").ToString
                    If listItems(i).CheckBoxText = "Completed" Then
                        listItems(i).CheckBoxCheck = True
                    Else
                        listItems(i).CheckBoxCheck = False
                    End If
                    FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And now I need that when I select some row that has checkbox and click button to find the record ID row and update the database:

```
Private Sub btnTaskDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTaskDone.Click
    If FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.OfType(Of UserTasks)().Any(Function(cb) cb.CheckBox1.Checked = False) Then
        'At least one CheckBox in myGroupBox is checked.
        MsgBox("Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Yeyy!")
        UpdateRecordDB(the id of the checkbox user control to update table)
    Else
        MsgBox("No Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What should happen if more than checkbox is checked?

Comment: (To set the checkbox, you could use `listItems(i).CheckBoxCheck = (listItems(i).CheckBoxText = "Completed")`. The parentheses are not necessary, but they can make it easier to read.)

Comment: I keep seeing the same code over and over as you re-ask the question. It is never corrected.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: access to UserTasks then get checkbox in usercontrol by control index

```
For Each cc As UserTasks In FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls
    If DirectCast(cc.Controls.Item(5), CheckBox).Checked = True then
        MsgBox("Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Yeyy!")
        UpdateRecordDB(the id of the checkbox user control to update table)
    Else
        MsgBox("No Checkbox Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
    End If
Next
```

`cc.Controls.Item(5)` is order of control in UserTasks
or you can test type of control by `If TypeOf cc.Controls.Item(5) Is CheckBox Then` then test checked state.

Demo: [image]